# At least how many of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2017}$ must be integers?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2017}$ be positive rational numbers such that $x_k+\dfrac{1}{x_{k+1}} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $k = 1,2,\ldots,2017$ where $x_1 = x_{2018}$. At least how many of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2017}$ must be integers?

Let $x_i = \dfrac{i}{i+1}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq 2016$ and let $x_{2017} = 2017$. Then this sequence of positive rationals satisfies the question with only $1$ integer. Is it possible to get $0$ integers?

Comment: Sounds like a riddle from a still running math competition. They love to include the current year in a non-trivial form.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to give help on this at the moment? Does anyone know whether the contest / exam in question (if any) has already ended?

Comment: @TobErnack I found the question on AoPS and I am pretty sure it is not from an ongoing competition as all the problems were released at the same time.

Comment: Paste the reference in here